# Open install page directly in play store

Tags: javascript, html, web

This is web development question and nothing to do with android programming.
If we go to the page like: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lila.apps.maze
we see an install button by clicking which we see the popup with install button.

Few days ago I read somewhere that by adding a GET request parameter in the URL we can directly land on a webpage with that install popup which looks like the following screen:

[image]

Can some  help me finding that extra parameter which should be present at the end of url to get to that install popup page. The parameter name was something starting with the character 'r'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's rdid parameter, for example https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.homesnap&rdid=com.homesnap instead of https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.homesnap